# Validate Angular FireStore rules without Google OAuth

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I have set-up a Google Firestore database and I want to secure the rules.
I already have users in my ACTUAL database and not everyone has a Google Account, so I want to authenticate them in any other way so I can validate if they can access a database item.

At this moment I can use code like:
`this.firestore.collection('myCollection').doc('IDHERE').delete();`

Would it be possible to generate a user-specific key from my back-end and save that to every item and then add a rule to see if this key is submitted?
So I want to add a certain key to the delete function above to let Firebase check for it in the item.
I can only see that you can check for an auth.user.id, but I want to check it in another way if possible!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Giving certain users certaim permissions to read (get, list operations) or write (delete,update,write operations) your database is possible. A combination of [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#auth-required) and [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) would be the most optimal solution. Now I understand that you may want to use a custom authentication method (using a "private key" to validate the user identity). You can validate data on a certain field. See link below.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation

Answer (score 0):

You can access every field inside collection->document and check for is value.
In my case i created a role based authentication so if the user is connected via google or with my custom Auth i will check for the proper role to define if he can execute the desired operation.

Example with boolean role;

```
match /CollectionName/{document} {
  function canAccess(role) {
    return resource.data.role == true;
  }
    allow read;
    allow update: if canAccess('role1');
    allow create,delete: if canAccess('role2');
}
```

As mentioned by @sllopis the attached [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) contains the above flow.